# Binding Eloquent params with DB::raw but not DB::select(DB:raw())

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a user search bar that allows clients to search for users by name, username or user role name (e.g. admin, manager etc).

In my query, I use DB::raw to concat the following fields: `user.forename + user.surname + role.name + user.username` so that the user can search any of the four fields, and can search for `John` or `Smith` or `John Smith`.

In my `orWhere` query, I use DB::raw to do the concat'ing, but I can't find an Eloquent example of how to bind params to `DB::raw` that doesn't include the outer wrapper `DB::select(DB::raw())`, and I've tried using `:searchTerm` and passing in an associative array as the second argument of `DB::raw` and I've also tried using `LIKE ?` in both situations, the `$filters['searchFilter']` returns null *in the dumped, bound query*, but a `dd()` of `$filters['searchFilters']` shows that it is definitely set.

Using `sprintf()` doesn't give me any protection from SQL injection. Is there a better way to do this?

```php
$users->where(function ($query) use ($filters) {
    $query->orWhere(
        DB::raw("CONCAT(users.forename, ' ', users.surname, ' ', CASE WHEN roles.name IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE roles.name END, ' ', users.username)"),
       'LIKE',
       sprintf('%%%s%%', $filters['searchFilter'])
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by using `->orWhereRaw` as follows:

```
        $users->where(function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
            $query->orWhereRaw('users.forename LIKE ?', [sprintf('%%%s%%', $searchTerm)]);
            $query->orWhereRaw('users.surname LIKE ?', [sprintf('%%%s%%', $searchTerm)]);
            $query->orWhereRaw('CONCAT(users.forename, \' \', org_users.surname) LIKE ?', [sprintf('%%%s%%', $searchTerm)]);
            $query->orWhereRaw('users.username LIKE ?', [sprintf('%%%s%%', $searchTerm)]);
            $query->orWhereRaw('CASE WHEN roles.name IS NOT NULL THEN auth_roles.name ELSE \' \' END LIKE ?', [sprintf('%%%s%%', $searchTerm)]);
        });
```